# Maven not running cucumber tests

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, automated-tests

Can anyone suggest why I am not able to run any test using Maven.

1. Surefire plugin is configured
2. Glue code is set under runner class
3. "Test" is appended to the runner class

Note: If I run my `RunnerTest.java` file as Junit it runs all scenarios properly. Only when I run it using Maven, no tests are run.

Have I missed any dependency? or is there any conflict happening?
Please refer my project structure image attached and my POM file.

[Project structure Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4cp0.jpg)

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.cucumber</groupId>
<artifactId>MavenCucumber_RocketTV</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>MavenCucumber_RocketTV</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
        <artifactId>surefire-junit4</artifactId>
        <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>19.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-htmlunit-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.52.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-safari-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.reporting</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-reporting-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.23</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.mkolisnyk</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-reports</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-html</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.picocontainer</groupId>
        <artifactId>picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
        <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${env.JAVA_HOME}/lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
        <version>2.12.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20090211</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-transcoder</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-util</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-bridge</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-css</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-svg-dom</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
        <artifactId>batik-ext</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
        <artifactId>ant-nodeps</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.cobertura</groupId>
        <artifactId>cobertura</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Comment: How do you run maven build from command line? (If you want me to see your reply start it with @Eugene S)

Comment: I can see you have done some customization to your `Cucumber.class` runner. Just to make sure that's not the source of this problem, try to replace it with the original runner and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: How are you running with Maven? (Which commands/options are you providing and how?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971167/cucumberjvmmaventests-dosent-run-from-command-line-through-maven?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

I was facing the same issue with Junit 5.5.2 and maven 3.6. The tests run fine from IntelliJ but maven does not run the tests.

Maven 3.6.0 was released on October 24th, 2018. This release includes version 2.22.0 of the Maven Surefire Plugin (unit test runner) and 2.22.0 of the Maven Failsafe (integration test runner) plugin. The 2.22.0 releases include support for JUnit.

Keeping all the dependencies as it is and adding maven-surefire-plugin 2.12.4 fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4):

adding surefire plugin solved the issue for me.

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/CucumberRunner*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the issue was `dryRun` enabled.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = {"pretty"}, dryRun = true,
        features = "src/test/resources/features",
        glue = "com/exelate/cucumber")
public class CucumberRunnerTest {
}
```

`dryRun` set to true means to only check that every Step mentioned in the Feature file has corresponding code written in Step Definition file. After removing it, I see that `maven clean install` fails when one of the scenario fails (which is the expected result).

Answer (score 1):

Rai Gupta's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58640878/4424636) is right. The dependency was an issue for me also.

I saw too many "Append your runner class with Test, move the runner class into TEST folder" etc. and these make *no* sense since you are just destroying the whole design and it will end horribly designed framework.

The `JUnit` and `SureFire` plugins need to be aligned. I used:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

and

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
<version>2.12.4</version>
```

However, this came in with a parallel execution problem. I did not need it, so I removed it, but you can try different versions of the above dependency.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me thanks! Here are the surefire plugin settings I used.

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/RunTests*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

try put your `.feature` files into `src\test\resources\features`

or simply follow https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

```
mvn archetype:generate                      \
   -DarchetypeGroupId=io.cucumber           \
   -DarchetypeArtifactId=cucumber-archetype \
   -DarchetypeVersion=2.3.1.2               \
   -DgroupId=hellocucumber                  \
   -DartifactId=hellocucumber               \
   -Dpackage=hellocucumber                  \
   -Dversion=1.0.0-SNAPSHOT                 \
   -DinteractiveMode=false

cd hellocucumber

mvn test
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, problem solved by changing version of surefire plugin as follows (I added this plugin to sub module that includes cucumber tests),

```
   <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.19.1</version>
     </plugin>
```