# [Cucumber][JVM][Maven]Tests dosen't run from command line through maven

Tags: maven, testing, junit, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I am running tests using java, cucumber with Maven.
I am using Eclipse IDE. Also the pom.xml has cucumber dependencies.
I am running tests in two ways.

1. From Eclipse IDE: I run tests as Junit tests and the test results are successful.

2: From command promt: My test failed and below is the result.

- Here is the Pom.xml:

  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
      4.0.0

  ```
  <groupId>CCIRA_Test_Auto</groupId>
  <artifactId>CCIRA_Test_Auto</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>CCIRA_Test_Auto</name>

  <properties>
      <cucumber.version>1.2.0</cucumber.version>
      <picocontainer.version>2.15</picocontainer.version>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
          <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.5</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
          <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
          <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
          <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
          <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
          <version>2.44.0</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>4.11</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>log4j</groupId>
          <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.2.17</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>3.9</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
          <version>3.11-beta3</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
          <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.2</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>xerces</groupId>
          <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.0</version>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
      <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>

              <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                      <source>1.7</source>
                      <target>1.7</target>
                  </configuration>
              </plugin>
          </plugins>
      </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  ```
- My Runner Test:

  package ccira.helpers;

  ```
      import org.junit.runner.RunWith;



  import org.testng.annotations.Test;

  import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
  import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;



  @RunWith(Cucumber.class)

  @CucumberOptions(

  features = "C:/Users/rah/Documents/workspace/CCIRA_auto/src/ressouces/features",

  tags = {"@Personne"},

  glue={"ccira.stepDefinitions"},

  plugin ={
  "pretty",
  "html:results/cucumber",
  "json:results/cucumber.json",
  "junit:results/cucumber.xml",
  }
          )


  public class RunnerTest {
  }
  ```
- My output console :

> ```
> SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
>
> SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
>
> SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further   details.
>
> [INFO] Scanning for projects...
> [INFO]                                                                         
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [INFO] Building CCIRA_Test_Auto 0.0.1
> [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> [WARNING] The artifact xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:2.0.2 has been relocated to xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ CCIRA_Test_Auto ---
> [debug] execute contextualize
> [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rah\Documents\workspace\CCIRA_Test_Auto\src\main\resources
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ CCIRA_Test_Auto ---
> [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ CCIRA_Test_Auto ---
> [debug] execute contextualize
> [WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
> [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\rah\Documents\workspace\CCIRA_Test_Auto\src\test\resources
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ CCIRA_Test_Auto ---
> [INFO] No sources to compile
> [INFO] 
> [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ CCIRA_Test_Auto ---
> [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\rah\Documents\workspace\CCIRA_Test_Auto\target\surefire-reports
>
> -------------------------------------------------------
>  T E S T S
> -------------------------------------------------------
>
>
> Results :
>
>
> Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
>
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     [INFO] Total time: 10.051s
>     [INFO] Finished at: Mon Dec 05 09:30:10 GMT 2016
>     [INFO] Final Memory: 7M/62M
>     [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ```

Comment: What command did you use to run tests from command propmt?

Comment: I'm using mvn test

Answer (score 1):

The dependency

```
org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
```

is not defined in your pom.xml file.  However it is defined on your build path in your Eclipse project. Placing one (and only one) of slf4j-nop.jar, slf4j-simple.jar, slf4j-log4j12.jar, slf4j-jdk14.jar or logback-classic.jar on the class path should solve the problem.

I would add a dependency in your pom.xml, perhaps something like this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

**EDIT**

A less good but viable alternative is to utilize the Surefire plugin's [additionalClasspathElements](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/configuring-classpath.html) element "to add custom resources/JARs to your classpath. This will be treated as an absolute file system path, so you may want use ${basedir} or another property combined with a relative path. Note that additional classpath elements are added to the end of the classpath, so you cannot use these to override project dependencies or resources."

I said less good because it is better to track as dependencies in your pom.xml where if you update one dependency to a later version you can see the other dependencies that also have to be updated.  You might overlook jars specified down in the surefire plugin.

Comment: You might need to include additional dependencies so checkout this Maven repo [page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/1.7.21).

Answer (score 0):

Try to run using the below command from command prompt

**mvn clean test -Dcucumber.options="src/resources/features --tags @@Personne"**