# Maven building but not executing tests in Cucumber

Tags: java, selenium, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin, cucumber-junit

I'm trying to run my JUnit tests from the command line using `mvn verify`. I've already used clean command, so that isn't the problem. I can execute my tests on from Eclipse IDE, but not so from the command line.

Below is pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>BDDObsidianAutomation</groupId>
    <artifactId>ObsidianAutomation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>ObsidianAutomation</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <junit.version>4.13.2</junit.version>
        <cucumber.version>6.10.4</cucumber.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.8.1</maven.compiler.version>
        <maven.surefire.version>2.22.2</maven.surefire.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
            <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber6-adapter</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>


            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.surefire.version}</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>

                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*MyTestRunner.java</include>
                            </includes>

                            <parallel>methods</parallel>
                            <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                            <perCoreThreadCount>true</perCoreThreadCount>

                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Below is results from command line:
[image: maven command line screenshot]

My Test Runner file MyTestRunner.java under src/test/java and in myTestRunners package:

```java
package myTestRunners;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features = {"src/test/resources/appFeatures"},
        glue = {"stepDefinitions", "appHooks"},
        plugin = {"pretty", 
                  "com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:",
                  "timeline:test-output-thread/"
                }
        )

public class MyTestRunner {

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[Cucumber\]\[JVM\]\[Maven\]Tests dosen't run from command line through maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971167/cucumberjvmmaventests-dosent-run-from-command-line-through-maven)

Comment: Nope, unfortunately that didn't help. Successful build, but no running of TCs.

Comment: So after some debugging, seems the issue has to do with the parallel portion of the POM.xml file. I removed it and it is running from the command line.